# how to optimize many dynamic views in android?

Tags: android, loops, layout-inflater

I am programming for a calendar which shows 365 days of year of 4 years (more than 1400 view) where every day contains a LinearLayout which holds the text and background color of the date.

In logcat I receive memory leak and message that the activity is doing too much works. currently I generate LinearLayouts programmatically id a loop. How can I optimize the memory? using a view Inflater? putting all views in a hard coded XML? getting instance of an object and modify it? or what?

my current code:

```
LinearLayout item=null;
while (year<2020){
month=0;
while (month<12){
day=1;
while (day<365){
    item=new LinearLayout(this);
    item.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    //item.setTag(current date);
    myCalendarView.addView(item);
    day=day+1;

}
 month=month+1;
}
year=year+1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have so many views at once? Why don't you re-use the same views with different values? Can you post your code?

Comment: what do you mean from reuse? I have added my code.

Comment: Will a recyclerview help you here?

Comment: So you have over 1400 LinearLayouts with nothing in them..why? what is `myCalendarView`? Are you displaying this in a list? If that's the case then I'd suggest you use a `RecyclerView` that inflates an `xml` layout file as it's needed.

Comment: Are you getting a outofmemory message? or just an error that says you are doing too much work?

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need to show 1400 linearlayouts at once on the screen. So create only the views that appear on the screen and recycle views that have dissappeared from the screen.

If you want the user to input data for a specific day, and save/load that data, You will need some kind of data model like a database.